# "OSError: cannot write object arrays to a file in binary mode"

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-3.5

It must be one of those days. I have always been able to use function tofile to save data. But for some reason, today it's not working :)

```
import numpy as np

blah.....

print(type(blist))
npdata = np.array(blist)
print(type(npdata))
npdata.tofile('myfile.dat')
```

Gets me the following results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/context.py", line 67, in <module>
npdata.tofile('myfile.dat')
OSError: cannot write object arrays to a file in binary mode
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So it says I have the file open in binary mode. But I am not opening it in binary mode as far as I know.

EDIT (After Problem solved): I was assuming that blist was a list of integers when I posted this question. Instead it was a list of lists of integers. Problem was that when I created it I was getting a dtype=object instead of dtype=int32 that I was expecting.

Morale: Make sure to use np.append/np.extend correctly and always set the dtype explicitly.

Comment: Show some example data that reproduces the problem. Were you expecting an `object` dtype?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `tofile` docs, if the `sep` is the default value, it writes the array in binary mode.

```
In [714]: x
Out[714]: array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]], dtype=object)

In [715]: x.tofile('test')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-715-0ff8f3c688ad> in <module>()
----> 1 x.tofile('test')

OSError: cannot write object arrays to a file in binary mode
```

It opened the file in binary mode, but then found that the array is an object array, which it can't write that way.  The default binary mode is for quickly writing numbers to the file, not general objects.

Specifying a `sep`, makes it write in text mode, which in this case works:

```
In [716]: x.tofile('test',sep=',')

In [717]: cat test
[1, 2, 3],[1, 2]
```

I have another object array (from another question) that contains a generator.

```
In [719]: g.tofile('test',sep=',')

In [720]: cat test
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb266632c>
```

So in `text` mode, `tofile` writes the `str(x)` representation of the array to the file.

`np.save` is better at handling object arrays.  It uses `pickle` to encode the object that it can't write as regular arrays.  `np.load` can reload such a file.

Comment: Thanks. You helped me spot the problem. I was just assuming that I had a different dtype. Problem was that blist was not actually a list of integers but a list of lists, and np.array was creating a list of objects instead of a list of 'int32'.

Comment: So when I was creating my blist before in the code. I was using blist.append(), I should have been using blist.extend() instead.

Comment: As with my `x`, if the sublists differ in length, the array is object dtype.  If they all match in size, `np.array` prefers to make it 2d (or higher).

Comment: This is interesting hpaulj because if my lists had all been the same size. I would not have been able to catch this problem. My user would have caught it though.

Although my user is me tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the file in binary mode for writing:

```
with open(filename, 'wb'):
    do stuff
```

Let me know if this works for you!